# How to undo Use Auto Layout in Xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xib

I am trying to fix why a button is misplaced everytime I run my program on landscape. But on the Xib it is properly positioned. Now, I've checked the Use Auto Layout checkbox and I can't undo it. The design seems to be autoresizing from portrait to landscape. How can I undo it?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the misplaced view and how you'd like it to be? Also what consttaints does it have?

Comment: Don't try to go back.  Fix the constraints instead.  In IB, you can simulate rotation and check the layout.  Fix constraints as necessary.

Comment: I have two xib, and for now I need to go back to the old landscape view